# How to Select a value from drop down with span class. Conventional drop-down function does not work for span class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

By Default properties :

```
<span class="selectBox-label" style="width: 135px;">--Select--</span>
```

Few values when selected from dropdown are having the below properties:

```
<span class="selectBox-label" style="width: 135px;">Association</span>
<span class="selectBox-label" style="width: 135px;">Partnership</span>
```

Requireent is to select the values 'Association' or 'Partnership'

Comment: Instead of providing a tailor-made HTML update the question with the relevant text based HTML for further analysis

Comment: That's not actually a dropdown (select) - We probably need to see the code you tried plus the url to help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform click operation on the Drop down label, then perform click operation on the required option.

Can be done something similar to this

```
//Clicks on the dropdown
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='selectBox-label']")).click();
//Clicks on the required option
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Association']")).click();
```

Comment: Glad to know that :)